# The JDK is missing and is required to run some NetBeans modules what should i do to fix

Tags: java, netbeans

I am new with programing and i wanted to install  netbeans in my macbook but i kept having this text " The JDK is missing and is required to run some NetBeans modules Please use the --jdkhome command line option to specify a JDK installation or see http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqRunningOnJre for more information.”

Answer (score 0):

That means you need the Java Development Kit (JDK). It is important for running files and develop those. You can download the newest version of the JDK under: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html
If you already have a JDK installed you must change the config file of NetBeans.